# My button is working even though the input is set to "required"

Tags: javascript, html

I created a Form with an Input as a Text type and also a Button to execute a Javascript code.

```js
<input required type="text" id="bNum" value="" name="bNum" size="6" maxlength="6" placeholder="Badge Number" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">

<button onclick=" verify();return false;">Verify</button>

function verify () {
  var bno = document.getElementById("bNum").value;

  switch (bno) {
    case "AJC8":
      alert("You are a Verified member!")
      break;
        
    case "AJB0":
      alert("You are a Verified member!")
      break;
    
    default:
      alert("You are Not a Verified member!")
      break;
  }
}
```

If I click the button the function executes it and does not show that the field is required.

Comment: Is button and input both inside form? if so please provide your full form code

Comment: The `required` attribute doesn't affect whether a button receives the onclick event. If you want to verify if it has input you will need to do that in your `verify` function

Comment: In the shown code I don't see where you disable the button, and your function does not verify for requiered input. Please show more code and be more explicit.

Comment: The validation caused by `required` only triggers, when the form actually gets submitted. Your button _is_ a submit button - but the `return false;` prevents it from actually triggering the form submission.

Comment: Here's how to do this properly: https://jsfiddle.net/6vzsgk1L/

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing in multiple concepts and behaviors, and your expectations don't match the current specs for these HTML attributes.

This is what the MDN says for the `required` attribute of the [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element:

> **required**
>
> required is a Boolean attribute which, if present, indicates that the user must specify a value for the input **before the owning form can be submitted**. The required attribute is supported by text, search, url, tel, email, date, month, week, time, datetime-local, number, password, checkbox, radio, and file inputs.

Emphasis added by me. Note that `required` attribute will only block a form's submission.
Meaning that it would only present the action of submitting a `<form>` element, which is not what you are doing here.

`required` simply doesn't block other interactions, although you could rely on it to implement your own blocking logic in your JS code and control the interaction with your elements.

For instance, you could add an onClick listener on the button and check whether your input is marked as "required" and has an empty value.